# How to find a string occuring between two other strings on other lines

Tags: grep, latex

How would I search for a certain string that is preceded by another string, in most cases several lines up, and followed by another string, i.e. contained in a certain environment?

```
\begin{quote}
%several lines of text
\footnote{%
%probably a few more lines of footnote content
}
%several lines of further text
\end{quote}
```

Thus I am searching for footnotes (starting with `\footnote{`) contained in a quote environment (starting with `\begin{quote}`, ending with `end{quote}`, in most cases spanning over several lines). Actually, in reality I should search for another environment contained in footnotes which occur inside quote environments, thus adding a second layer of conditions, but probably once I understand the simplified example I can figure out my real world problem. The actual environment I search for occurs about 150 times in a directory containing about 20 `.tex` files, constituting the sources for a roughly 500 pages book supposed to go to print in a few days, and that particular combination produces an undesired effect, which many times, if not looking carefully, will go unnoticed.

As output of my search I would like to get the file name in which the match occurs (I would probably search through `*tex`, although, if that should be too complicated, I could also work with a bash for loop), and its line number.

One will also have to keep in mind that

```
\begin{quote}
%something
\end{quote}
%something
\footnote{%
%something
}
%something
\begin{quote}
%something
\end{quote}
```

would be something occurring many times, but it would be a false positive.

Comment: Add the expected output to the question. Does it also need to contain the two strings themselves?

Comment: @NasirRiley I've added the expected output. No, the strings themselves do not need to be included in the output.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with `grep`, you'll need something more capable like `awk` or `perl`.  Here's a very simple example of doing this in perl:

```
$ cat find-fn-in-quote.pl 
#!/usr/bin/perl

while(<>) {
  # strip comments so that we ignore commented-out quotes & footnotes.
  s/%[^%].*//;

  # detect beginning and end of quotes
  if (m/\Qbegin{quote}\E/) { $qt = 1; $ql = $.};
  if (m/\Qend{quote}\E/)   { $qt = 0 };

  if (eof) {
    # reset line-counter ($.) after every input file
    close(ARGV);

    # reset $qt to zero, in case of unbalanced begin/end{quote}
    $qt = 0;
  };

  # skip to next input line if we're not inside a quote.
  next unless ($qt);

  if (m/\\footnote\{/) {
   print "$ARGV: found footnote beginning on line $. inside quote beginning on line $ql\n";
   # For terse output, comment out or delete the print statement above
   # and un-comment one of these:
   #printf "%s:fn=%i:q=%i\n", $ARGV, $., $ql;
   #printf "%s:%i:%i\n", $ARGV, $., $ql;
  };

};
```

Note: This script is not capable of properly handling nested `begin{quote}`s. I doubt that this will be a problem, as it's unlikely to happen outside of contrived examples.  It also assumes that a quote will exist entirely within one file - in fact, the script deliberately enforces this to ensure that a bug in one input file (i.e. a missing `end{quote}`) won't affect subsequent files.

I created 3 text files to test this with.  `input1.txt` contains your first sample input.  `input2.txt` contains your second sample input with the false-positives you don't want to match.  `input3.txt` contains input2.txt followed by input1.txt (i.e. `cat input2.txt input1.txt > input3.txt`).   Running the script on these input files gives the following output:

```
$ ./find-fn-in-quote.pl *.txt
input1.txt: found footnote beginning on line 3 inside quote beginning on line 1
input3.txt: found footnote beginning on line 14 inside quote beginning on line 12
```

Comment: Works! But made me aware of the fact that the problem not only occurs in `quote` environments, but also in `verse`, possibly in others. How do I add the word alternative to the regex?

Comment: I wouldn't use regex alternation for that because quotes and verses are independent of each other.   instead, copy the tests for `\begin{quote}` and `\end{quote}`, modify them to test for `verse` instead, and use a different variable (e.g. `$vs`) instead of `$qt`.   Then change the `next unless ...` line to `next unless ($qt or $vs);`.   You'd also need to produce different output depending on whether you found a footnote inside a quote or inside a verse.

Comment: alternatively, write two versions of the script - one to find footnotes inside quotes, another to find footnotes inside verses.

Comment: Yes, two versions will be the easier solution. Anyway, I'm taking the opportunity to play a bit with perl, and try to make it work for both cases in one script. Should that become too complicated I can still work with two separate scripts.

Comment: have fun!   perl's pretty much the ideal text processing language, it can do everything that sed, awk, grep, tr, cut, and many others can do....and that's even before you start looking at the CPAN module library.    BTW, I often use little perl scripts to generate TeX output - e.g. to create enumerate or description lists or tables from a database (or a csv file. or whatever) or to convert plain, or structured or markdown text to consistently formatted tex.

Comment: One task I will have to do at some point is to convert a bunch of critical editions from LaTeX to TEI (XML). I've (mostly) done the first of them manually, greatly aided by vim macros, but it still took quite a number of hours. I guess if one could script the task in perl that would greatly accelerate the process, even if still one has to carefully check all of the output, and sometimes one will get stuck by one or the other irregularity in the LaTeX source code to which one will then have to re-adapt one's script.

Comment: There are lots of perl modules for doing stuff to or with latex source files - 161 results from https://metacpan.org/search?q=latex.  The hard part is sorting through them to find the ones that can do what you want.    [Latex::TOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/LaTeX::TOM) looks like it might be useful to you: "This module provides a parser which parses and interprets (though not fully) LaTeX documents and returns a tree-based representation of what it finds. [...] especially useful to anyone who wants to do processing of LaTeX documents that requires extraction of plain-text information [...]"

Comment: perl also has good library modules for working with XML.

Answer (score 2):

An `awk` version of the

```
awk 'FNR==1{looking=0; print  FILENAME}
  $0~/begin{quote}/{looking=1;next}
  $0~/end{quote}/{looking=0;next}
  looking&&$0~/footnote{/{print FNR, $0}' *.tex
```

Simply starts "looking" when a quote begins and stops when it ends.

Like @cas example this resets at each opening of a file.

If you are going to be looking inside the footnote for another environment then it gets trickier as you will need to start looking for for balanced `}` for the `\footnote` on different lines, which is a different animal.

Comment: Yeah, correctly handling nested curly-braces etc gets **very** complicated.  I first thought of using perl's [Regexp::Common::balanced](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common::balanced) module and then I realised it didn't need to be anywhere near that complicated - all it needs to do is detect whether a footnote is inside quote or not.

Comment: @cas surely it's OP's need to find an environment inside the footnote that drives...... the need to encapsulate the search for that environment within the `footnote{..\n...whatever other environments..\n....}` scope. Finding the footnote in the quote/verse is a walk in the park.

Comment: huh?         (extra text to satisfy min length of 15 characters)

Answer (score 1):

GNU awk:

```
awk '
/^\\end{quote}$/ && fire        {report = report OFS str}
/^\\end{quote}$/                {block=cont=fire=0; str=""}
/^\\begin{quote}$/              {block=1}
block && /^\\footnote{%$/       {cont=1; str=FNR; next}
block && cont && /}/            {fire=1;cont=0}
ENDFILE                         {if(report)print FILENAME report; report = ""}
' *.tex
```

Output format:

```
filename line_number line_number ...
```

All line numbers with matches are output in one line for each file. File names without matches are not displayed.